# Dynamically change the text of a psd?

Tags: php, apache, photoshop, dynamic-image-generation

Here is my problem:

A designer creates a banner ad showing a sale.  For example: 10% off all items. The sale changes every other weekend from 10% to 15%. The design of the ad and the position of the text changes from week to week or day to day.  I would like to automate the text change and banner creation.

Is there a way to dynamically open up a psd that holds the design and change the text and output the image using a LAMP server?

The image file does not have to be a psd. I guess it can be any format that would allow me to do this easily.

I did some research and found a program called imagemagick. I could not find any documentation on how to solve my problem  using this  software.

I don’t know if this is the right software to use or not. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely possible - you'll create an image file with no text in it, in some format Imagemagick understands (i.e., not PSD - JPEG or PNG are two common formats), and then draw some text on top of it. The same technique is used to produce those captcha images.

You can find a really basic tutorial showing how this might work [here](http://www.phpro.org/examples/Write-Text-To-Image.html).

Obviously you can do much more complex things than that page is showing, but it should get you started. The full PHP ImageMagick API is very well documented in the main PHP documentation, which can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php).